# Core Data class lost

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, core-data

I have a class hierarchy for my Core Data classes.  My base class is AccountMO.  My leaf classes are StudentAccountMO and ActivityAccountMO.  I am saving all the accounts in an array of type AccountMO.  Here's my code:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Account", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
if isStudentVal
{
     var myAccount:StudentAccountMO
     myAccount = StudentAccountMO(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
     myAccount.name = StudentNameField.text!
     myAccount.teacherName = TeacherNameField.text!
     myAccount.gradeOrLevel = GradeField.text!
     myAccount.schoolOrDept = SchoolField.text!
     myAccount.picture = UIImagePNGRepresentation(CustomPicture.image!)
     myAccount.timestamp = curTime
     ShareData.sharedInstance.accounts.insert(myAccount, atIndex: 0)
}
else
{
     var myAccount: ActivityAccountMO
     myAccount = ActivityAccountMO(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
     myAccount.name = StudentNameField.text!
     myAccount.teacherName = TeacherNameField.text!
     myAccount.gradeOrLevel = GradeField.text!
     myAccount.schoolOrDept = SchoolField.text!
     myAccount.picture = UIImagePNGRepresentation(CustomPicture.image!)
     myAccount.timestamp = curTime
     ShareData.sharedInstance.accounts.insert(myAccount, atIndex: 0)
}

do
{
     try managedContext.save()
}
catch let error as NSError
{
     print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

Also, I have the following code in a different function that tests to see which class it was saved as.  I always get AccountMO!

```
if let myStudentAcc = ShareData.sharedInstance.currentAccount as? StudentAccountMO
{
     personAccountButton.backgroundColor = MyVariables.outlineColor
     personAccountButton.setTitleColor(MyVariables.backgroundColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
else if let activityAcc = ShareData.sharedInstance.currentAccount as? ActivityAccountMO
{
     activityAccountButton.backgroundColor = MyVariables.outlineColor
     activityAccountButton.setTitleColor(MyVariables.backgroundColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
else
{
      //ALWAYS ENDS UP HERE AS TYPE AccountMO!     
      var myVar = ShareData.sharedInstance.currentAccount
}
```

I realize now it might be relevant.  Here is how the [Account] is stored:

```
class ShareData
{
     class var sharedInstance: ShareData
     {
         struct Static
         {
              static var instance: ShareData?
              static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
         }
         dispatch_once(&Static.token)
         {
              Static.instance = ShareData()
         }

         return Static.instance!
     }
     var queryGroup = dispatch_group_create()
     var accounts : [AccountMO!] = []
     var currentAccount : AccountMO!
     var counter = 0
     var mySort = sortType.ByName

     var buttonName: String!
     var indexOfCurrentAccount = 0

     func updateAccount(newValue: AccountMO)
     {
           accounts[indexOfCurrentAccount] = newValue
     }    
 }
```

Why does it always cast to AccountMO?  I would think it would keep the class it was created as.  If it interests you, the AccountMOs are stored in a [AccountMO].  Any help as to why the software is shaving off the class it was created as, would be helpful.  Thanks for your consideration of this matter.

Sincerely,
Sean

Comment: How is `currentAccount` defined and created?

Comment: That's a good question. I have changed the code to if let myStudentAcc = ShareData.sharedInstance.accounts[ShareData.sharedInstance.indexOfCurrentAccount] as? StudentAccountMO and that still doesn't work.

Comment: Hmmm.  I see you are using the same entity definition for each.  I think the CoreData initialiser uses the class defined for the relevant entity, effectively ignoring the class that calls the initialiser.  Check by testing the class immediately after creating `myAccount`.

Comment: pbasdf You solved it!  Thank you very much!  That was definitely the problem.

Comment: If you want distinct classes, you could set up your entity structure to mirror your class structure - a parent entity with class AccountMO and two subentities with classes StudentAccountMO and ActivityAccountMO respectively.